# Input a value based on the values of 2 other cells

Tags: excel, function

Lets say we have the following table

```
               A                        B           C
1| MAC                        |      Not Ok   |
2| WIN                        |  Not tested   |
3       
4| number of WIN -OK          |               |   
5| number of WIN - Not Ok     |               |
6| number of WIN - Not Tested |               |  1
7| number of MAC Ok           |               |
8| number of MAC Not Ok       |               |  1
9| number of MAC Not Tested   |               |
```

Where A1:A2 is a dropdown list containing "MAC" and  "WIN" and B1:B2 is a dropdown list containing "Ok", "Not Ok" and "Not Tested"

I want to count in the cells C4:C9, the number of Win - OK, Win - Not OK, etc

Can something like this be done without VBA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this formula.. Hope this will clear your doubts..[image]